# How to redirect to modal from php file?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I need redirect to my modal from my php file. I'm using header(Location:) but I don't know how redirect please help me ;)

Thanks!

PHP File :

```
if($cargo == "personal"){  
  $query = "UPDATE empleado SET cargo='bloqueado' WHERE rut='$rut'";

  if ($conex->query($query) == TRUE) {
     header("Location:TO MODAL");
} else {
     console.log('error!');
}
```

Modal :

```
echo "<div class='modal fade' id='infodetallada".$fila['rut']."'>";
```

Comment: **I would urge you to use _pdo to prevent SQL injection_.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: use `header('Location: path/to/file/filename.php')`

First things first: Your are mixing up the languages PHP and JS.

`if ($conex->query($query) == TRUE) ...` is *PHP*

`console.log(..);` is *JS*.
You should replace that with something like `die('error!');` which will stop the execution of the script and shows an error message.

If you want to redirect to *model.php*, you could write something like:

```
if($cargo == "personal"){  
    $query = "UPDATE empleado SET cargo='bloqueado' WHERE rut='$rut'";

    if ($conex->query($query)) {
       header("Location: model.php");
    } else {
       die('error!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A modal is a Bootstrap JavaScript element which is used on the client side of things. PHP works on the server end of things.

As weird as it may sound, PHP cannot make a modal pop-up (unless you're using some fuzzy, weird-ass code). What you'll need is JavaScript (or jQuery) to help you make that Modal appear as it should.

Since you have jQuery included follow the following tutorial;
[PHP and AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp)
Please let me know if you can follow and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Pass an argument via url, fetch it via js and trigger the modal with js when this arg value is passed by.

Answer (score 0):

As they said, you must to use javascript in order to popup the modal, via some hash, like this:

`// on the footer of redirect page
    if (window.location.hash == "#openm") {
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    }`